# Process child creating a new session

Tags: c, linux, process, child-process

I'm trying to write a program that creates a child proces. The child process creates a new session. Also, it must be verified that the child process has become the leader of the group and that it has no control terminal.

It always shows me `waiting for parent to die`, entered an infinite loop. What I need to change, not to display like that?

this is my code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    pid_t pid;

    if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {
        perror("fork error");
        return -1;
    } else
    if (pid == 0) {
        // Wait for the parent to die.
        while (getppid() != 1) {
            printf("Waiting for parent to die.\n");
            sleep(1);
        }

        pid = setsid();

        printf("pid, pgid and \"sid\" should be the same:\n");
        printf("pid: %d pgid: %d sid: %d\n", getpid(), getpgrp(), getsid(0));

        if ((open("/dev/tty", O_RDWR)) < 0) {
            printf("Child has no controlling terminal!\n");
        } else {
            printf("Child has a controlling terminal!\n");
        }

    } else {
        if ((open("/dev/tty", O_RDWR)) < 0) {
            printf("Parent has no controlling terminal!\n");
        } else {
            printf("Parent still has a controlling terminal!\n");
        }
        _exit(0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming that your original parent process never prints anything to the screen.

Comment: I compiled your code exactly as typed, although I'm on a Mac, and it worked fine.  Not sure what to tell you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that:

```
while (getppid() != 1) {
  printf("Waiting for parent to die.\n");
  sleep(1);
}
```

off course return always a value different to 1.
For waiting the dead of the parent process, you can use wait(NULL), so you can change the block that i wrote up with:

```
wait(NULL)
```

when i execute the program with this change i receive this output:

```
Parent still has a controlling terminal!
pid, pgid and "sid" should be the same:
pid: 2581 pgid: 2581 sid: 2581
Child has no controlling terminal!
```

Is this what you need?

Comment: thank you but no. 
`wait` is used to read the child's condition, but I have no other children in the child, so  `wait` does nothing either. 
On the other part if I wait for the parent to finish having the control terminal, then probably the child will receive a waiting signal. Rather after `setsid` I have to wait

Comment: Maybe you can pass the pid of the parent with a pipe (or other IPC mechanisme) to the child and use waitpid(parent_pid) for wait the temination of the parent.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*method1 need sleep,too fast exit will fail
even exit current process the targetname still alive!
add [&] make u run next line without wait*/

#include <stdlib.h>
```

method1:

```
system("setsid /root/Downloads/targetname &");
usleep(2000000);
exit(0);
```

method2:

```
pid_t pid;
if ( (pid = fork()) )
{
    printf("current process group id is %d\n", (int) getpgrp());
}
else
{
    printf("sub A id is now %d %d %d\n", getpid(), getpgid(getpid()), getsid(getpid()));        
    setsid();
    printf("sub B id is now %d %d %d\n", getpid(), getpgid(getpid()), getsid(getpid()));        
    system("/root/eclipse_android/targetname/targetname usb 1 2 3 &");
    printf("child's process group id is now %d\n", (int) getpgrp());
}

exit(0);
```

in targetname also need setsid() to targetname.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    printf("targetname F id is now %d %d %d\n", getpid(), getpgid(getpid()), getsid(getpid()));

    setsid(); //totally independent in gid sid

    printf("targetname G id is now %d %d %d\n", getpid(), getpgid(getpid()), getsid(getpid()));

}
```

ps: system function can use posix_spawn function too